# CountIF cell value matches adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a table used to track document versions and whether or not a user has read the most up to date version.
I want to track the number of up to date documents read per user and I'm really struggling with CountIF.

[image]

How do I count the number of times UserA matches Doc version?

What I have tried is =COUNTIF(A1:A12, "="&B1:B12) which gives multiple rows of results I don't really understand. I have also tried =COUNTIF(A1:A12, "="&B1) but of course that just matched to B1.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve your problem? I assume the correct answer here is 9?

Comment: This is a small part of a much larger dataset I am working with. It would be impractical to count the times the values match. I can could the number of times the UserA row matches the first cell but I can't figure out how to make the cell being matched move down with the cell being assessed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what your full dataset would count to, we are talking and looking at the sample data you have provided. See [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Provide your readers with clear sample data, a given issue with your **own** attempt at solving your issue, and let us know what the expected results are.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I've updated the question with a couple of examples of what I've tried.

Comment: Right, the only thing missing is the expected result for your sample, but see if `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A13=B2:B13))` works for you.

Comment: Nearly there! But yes you're answer is exactly what I was looking for. 
(wouldn't normally comment to say answer correct but I can't mark it as correct in a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment by @JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637744/countif-cell-value-matches-adjacent-cell/66640916#comment117800019_66637744) answered the question:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A13=B2:B13))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can at least attach a sample file.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A13<>B1:B13))
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. 
I'm wanting find out the number of times column A matches column B. 
In my example in the question both columns match 9 times. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A23-B2:B23=0)*(A2:A23<>""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(A1, "="& B1)
```

Then copy/paste it to all cells.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).